# Can't open directory but am member of group that owns directory

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I feel like I'm missing something about permissions. My user is st.
I am a part of the group that owns the folder. I have r-x permissions via the group. But I get permission denied when trying to access.

What am I missing?

> cd nodejs-node-red/
>
> bash: cd: nodejs-node-red/: Permission denied

> ll
>
> drwxr-x---  4 nodejs-node-red nodejs-node-red 4096 Feb  6 10:44 nodejs-node-red

> pwd
>
> /var/lib

> cat /etc/group
>
> st:x:1000:nodejs-node-red,st
>
> nodejs-node-red:x:962:st,nodejs-node-red

> cat /etc/passwd
>
> st:x:1000:1000::/home/st:/bin/bash
>
> nodejs-node-red:x:962:962::/var/lib/nodejs-node-red:/usr/bin/nologin

Comment: What does `id st` return? Have you logged out then back in since adding yourself to the `nodejs-node-red` group?

Comment: I have not logged out, I didn't think that was required.

$ id st

uid=1000(st) 
gid=1000(st) 
groups=1000(st),11(ftp),19(log),50(games),999(adm),998(wheel),986(uucp),983(systemd-journal),982(rfkill),33(http),962(nodejs-node-red)

Comment: I just opened another login (ctrl+alt+f2) and could cd .. so I do need to re-login after changing groups.

Comment: Glad it as something simple.